# How to update Hibernate delivered with Play?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, ivy

Play frameworks comes with an old Hibernate version (3.6.1). How can I update Hibernate in my Play application? Via Ivy?

Following Pere's advice I tried:

```
require:
    - play
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.8 force: true

repositories:
    - jboss:
        type: http
        root: "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        contains:
            - org.jboss -> *
            - org.jboss.javaee -> *
            - org.hibernate -> *
```

But nothing happens. When I'm looking at the Ivy cache directory Hibernate 3.6.8 isn't there and it seems like nothing happens at all.

Comment: is this the right place to ask this type of question?

Comment: I think it is, so upvoted! @PereVillega solution seems on the right track but.. it's not working for me. Any luck on your side?

Comment: @PereVillega solution works perfectly when you add the jboss repository and specify the right dependencies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Pere Villegas answer I found the solution to update Hibernate delivered with Play:

```
require:
    - play
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.9.Final:
        force: true
    - org.hibernate -> hibernate-validator 4.2.0.Final

repositories:
    - jboss:
        type: iBiblio
        root: "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public"
        contains:
            - org.jboss -> *
            - org.jboss.javaee -> *
            - org.hibernate -> *
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to force the new version as stated [in here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency) (note: I've not tested this and I can't right now).

you should add thsi your dependencies.yml

```
 - org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.1
        force: true
```

Replace version number by the version of your choice. The flag *force* should override the defaults used by Play

**EDIT:**

You may need to point to the JBoss repository, see Stephano's comment:

> I followed strictly the play dependencies maven2 example and added
>   org.jboss -> * AND org.jboss.javaee -> * and works perfectly

Comment: I tried with "- org.hibernate -> hibernate-core 3.6.8.Final: force: true" but got a missing dependencies: "org.jboss.javaee->jboss-jacc-api_JDK4 1.1.0" which ends with `A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Unable to get the default Bean Validation factory` after play run. Any idea?! Thanks!

Comment: @Stefano you may need to adda new repository (JBoss one) to find that extra dependency

Comment: thanks Pere, that pointed me to the right direction. I followed strictly the play dependencies [maven2 example](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/dependency#Mavenrepositories) and added `org.jboss -> *` **AND**  `org.jboss.javaee -> *` and works perfectly !

Comment: PS. you might want to edit your answer with the repository tip, I think it will help more than one!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Play comes with hibernate out-of-the-box, but doesn't have any strong dependencies on it, so you should be able to just replace the hibernate libraries.

See [Play without JPA/Hibernate?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/GXFwU3tGf9g/discussion) from the [Play framework google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/play-framework).

I'm no expert, so I would confirm this on that list.